# How to retrive the values from database from dropdownlist onselect in php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to retrive  record from database and place that appropriate value into textarea while i am select an option form dropdownlist onselect event.

Here i attach my form Screen shot,[image: image1]

In this form when i select an Sms templete name means the particular discription is placed into that description textarea box. (Onselect event.)

My table : sms_template
Fields : id, sms_template, Description

How to do that in PHP-MySql or any scripting language. (Ajax, javascript)

Comment: **What Have You Tried So Far ?**

Comment: i having no idea about this please help me

Comment: Atleast paste your code of this modal form .

Comment: there are ample tutorials and answers out there. We don't code it for you and for many reasons. Stack isn't a *"how-to"* site. You need to try something.

Comment: You've been given an answer below, ask them. Sure is a lot of guesswork here, and with NO code provided by you. I hope you won't be wasting the guy's time.

Comment: Ha Ha @Fred-ii- Just giving a small bit of code. He will try. See, When I see `please help me` type of words.. I see myself in that position. A year ago, you all people helped me like this way only.

Comment: @NanaPartykar Yes I agree that we've all been there, but at the very least; the OP should have provided the codes they presently have (if any), including any relevant information in regards to their database. That's **if** they even have one, and which MySQL API they're using to connect with, *etc., etc., etc.* ;-) The question is way too broad and unclear at the same time. Good luck with this.

Comment: Yeah. I agree @Fred-ii- . Please, Please don't be angry. :D

Comment: @NanaPartykar hahaha, I'm not "angry", whatever gave you that impression? Plus, it's really hard to "sugar coat" this for the OP, especially with what they haven't done: "their homework" to research this, rather than have people "guess", because that's what this question will end up being, "pure guesswork". It'd need a total code writeup, including db/table creation codes, API connection, MySQL query, the whole 9 yds. I think you know what I mean here. I really take great joy in helping people and to help solve coding problems, but they must  learn how to help themselves first.

Answer (score 1):

Since, data not given properly. I am assuming from my side and giving a basic layout of it. 
I am assuming that you are having query for dropdown. Just change it as you want. But, don't change attribute name.

```
.
//Your code
.
<input type='text' name='custPhone'> <br>

<select class='smsTemplate' name='smsTemplateName'>
    // Your value coming from database. Write your query here
    <option data-description="Success Sms template description" value="Success Sms template"></option>
    <option data-description="Failure Sms template description" value="Failure Sms template"></option>
</select> <br>

<textarea class='showDescription'></textarea> <br>

.
//Your code
.
.



<script>
    $(function(){
          $('.smsTemplate').change(function(){
                 var smsDesc = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-description');
                 $(".showDescription").val(smsDesc);
          });
    });
</script>
```